# Problems getting my GTX 1050ti to work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I was unable to install the Nvidea GTX1050t driver on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, by following Nvidia's ["instructions"](https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/375.66/README/index.html).

I would appreciate any advice and help resolving this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can install nvidia drivers via apt.

Fist remove all not working drivers

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

Then add the repository for the drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the actual drivers

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384
```

After that `reboot`.

I had problem with `gdm3` so if the drivers still do not work and you are getting a black screen try installing `lightdm`.

Comment: You can install even newer versions.

Comment: I tried everything suggested here, got as far as `sudo apt-get install nvidia-375` when everything swithced off as it was displaying something to the effect of `Building initial package for 4.8.0-36-generic`. 
After rebooting, I would type in my login password, only to have the screen blip out and take me right back to the login screen. The only recourse I knew was to re-install Ubuntu at this point. I've installed `lightdm` as suggested an am going to try again.

Comment: I tried it, system shut off and locked me out of Ubuntu again. This time I got a better look at the offending operation: `Building initial module for 4.8.0-58-generic` I Re-installed Ubuntu from the bios for the fifth time. tried using the _Software & Updates_ tool to install it instead, same thing happened. Re-installed Ubuntu again. Hmmm... Maybe I should try a newer version of the driver, as Michael Bay suggested?